# Objective-C : No Matter what I do CIDetector is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, face-detection, ciimage

Trying to get a simple Proof of concept going with Apple's face detection API.  I've looked at a couple of other examples including Apple's SquareCam, and this one 
https://github.com/jeroentrappers/FaceDetectionPOC

based on these, it seems like I am following the correct pattern to get the APIs going, but I am stuck.  No matter what I do, the CIDetector for my face detector is always nil!!!

I would seriously appreciate any help, clues - hints - suggestions!

```
-(void)initCamera{
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];

AVCaptureDevice *device;
/*
if([self frontCameraAvailable]){
    device = [self frontCamera];
}else{
    device = [self backCamera];
}*/

device = [self frontCamera];
isUsingFrontFacingCamera = YES;
NSError *error = nil;

AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

if(input && [session canAddInput:input]){
    [session addInput:input];
}else{
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
    //make this Dlog...
}


videoDataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc]init];
NSDictionary *rgbOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
[videoDataOutput setVideoSettings:rgbOutputSettings];
[videoDataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];

videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
[videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoDataOutputQueue];
[[videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]setEnabled:YES];

if ([session canAddOutput:videoDataOutput]) {
    [session addOutput:videoDataOutput];
}




[self embedPreviewInView:self.theImageView];



[session startRunning];



}



-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer options:(__bridge NSDictionary *)attachments];


if(attachments){
    CFRelease(attachments);
}



UIDeviceOrientation curDeviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];


NSDictionary *imageOptions = @{CIDetectorImageOrientation:[self exifOrientation:curDeviceOrientation] };


NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyLow};

CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIFeatureTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];


NSArray *faceFeatures = [faceDetector featuresInImage:ciImage options:imageOptions];
if([faceFeatures count]>0){
    NSLog(@"GOT a face!");
    NSLog(@"%@", faceFeatures);

}


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    //NSLog(@"updating main thread");
});


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [this](http://nshipster.com/ios7/) article, because I was too and had the same problem. There's actually a bug in his code. The CIDetector instantiation should look like:

```
CIDetector *smileDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                            context:context 
                            options:@{CIDetectorTracking: @YES, 
                                      CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyLow}];
```

Note that the detector type is CIDetectorTypeFace, rather than CIDetectorSmile. CIDetectorSmile is a feature option rather than a detector type, so to extract just the smiles (and not all the faces), use this code:

```
NSArray *features = [smileDetector featuresInImage:image options:@{CIDetectorSmile: @YES}];
```

Comment: well that article is where I started out, but I decided to just try and get some facial recognition going first.  At this point I am still just frustrated that no matter how or where I try to instantiate an instance of any CIDetector, it remains nil.  I am fairly certain that I have all of the correct frameworks imported correctly.  As I referenced earlier, I am just trying to follow some of the patterns of other face detection examples so that is where most of this code has come from.  Happy to share full source, cause I'd love to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: WOW.  yea I missed that Completely.  Thank you! CIDetectorTypeFace.  **face palm**

Answer (score 1):

```
CIDetector *smileDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                            context:context 
                            options:@{CIDetectorTracking: @YES, 
                                      CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyLow}];
NSArray *features = [smileDetector featuresInImage:image options:@{CIDetectorSmile:@YES}];
if (([features count] > 0) && (((CIFaceFeature *)features[0]).hasSmile)) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(didFinishWritingImage), features);
} else {
    self.label.text = @"Say Cheese!"
}
```