# Face detection in IOS 8 and IOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8

Is any body know how to detect face detection in IOS 8 and IOS 7 using CIdetector. I'm facing issue in detecting face. 
I have tested in devices iPhone 6 plus ,iPhone 5s and iPhone 4s.

Reference link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html

http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/

All the above link code are tested but resultant is same.. Please help me

> ` CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:facePicture.image.CGImage];
>    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];                    // 1
>       NSDictionary *opts = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };      // 2
>       CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
>                                                 context:context
>                                                 options:opts];                    // 3

```
if([[image properties] valueForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyOrientation] == nil)
{
    opts = @{CIDetectorImageOrientation : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]};
}
else
{
    opts = @{CIDetectorImageOrientation : [[image properties] valueForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyOrientation]};
}
```

NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:image options:opts];`

Thanks In Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055760/objective-c-no-matter-what-i-do-cidetector-is-always-nil ------ use this one also

Comment: Can you post some code, so we can try to reproduce?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this CI [subclass](https://github.com/pnvd11/face-detector-subclass) for face detector. This class doesn't depend on image size input to detect face, and it has flexible size output.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CIDetector *smileDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                        context:context 
                        options:@{CIDetectorTracking: @YES, 
                                  CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyLow}];
NSArray *features = [smileDetector featuresInImage:image options:@{CIDetectorSmile: @YES}];
```

Comment: what is context over there? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

See below code..

```
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.imageView.image.CGImage];
CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                              context:nil options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];

NSDictionary *options = @{ CIDetectorSmile: @(YES) };
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:image options:options];

for(CIFaceFeature *feature in features) {
    NSLog(@"Smile %@", feature.hasSmile ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```